# How do you send a DM to users that react to a bot sent message? (Discord.JS)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Pretty much what the title says, but I just wanted to figure out how to get my bot to send a DM to anyone and everyone who reacts to the message it sends.

```
    name: "sign-up",
    description: "signup thing",
    category: "misc",
    execute(message, client){

        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        const say = args.join(" ");


        if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send(`You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`);
        }

        message.channel.send(say).then(message =>{
            message.react("✅")

        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ['✅'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
        };
        
        const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: 60000 });
        collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
            reaction.users.last().send('Some')
            .catch(console.error)
        });
        
    }
```

In this case, an admin will write a message (which comes up correctly as an args), and I have gotten this far where I just wanted to return the reaction users in my console. I am pretty much stuck here.

Apologies if the code is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code is missing `}` and you should try using `async/await` that will easier to look and understanding for newbie. And as your code of `filter` using on `createReactionCollector` you are capture emoji that reacted by who send bot command request not every user (`user.id === message.author.id`)

```js
    name: "sign-up",
    description: "signup thing",
    category: "misc",
    async execute(message, client){

        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        const say = args.join(" ");


        if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send(`You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`);
        }

        const newMsg = await message.channel.send(say)
        newMsg.react("✅")   
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return user.id === message.author.id;
        };
        const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: 60000 });
        collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
            if (r.emoji.name === '✅') {
               user.send('Some');
            }
        });
        
    }
```

Comment: This sort of helped, thank you, it didn't completely fix the problem though, I ended up fixing it myself.